# SMTPClient Send Failure: Can't Send Email in vb.net Despite Trying Multiple Ports and SSL

Tags: vb.net

Smtpclient send failure

Hello, I have been using smptclient for a long time in vb.net to send email, but now it doesn't work for me.
I have tried with true and false ssl
I have also tried with ports 465, 587 and 25

```
Public Sub EnviarEmail(ByVal pMensaje As String, ByVal pAsunto As String)
        Dim message As New MailMessage

        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
        message.From = New MailAddress(xEmailOrigen)

        message.To.Add(xEmailDestino)

        message.Body = pMensaje

        message.Subject = pAsunto

        message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal

        smtp.EnableSsl = xEmailOrigenSSL


        smtp.Port = xEmailOrigenPuertoSMTP

        smtp.Host = xEmailOrigenHostSMTP
        'smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(xEmailOrigenUsuario, xEmailOrigenContraseña)

        smtp.Send(message)
```

Thank you

Probé con distintos puertos y esperaba que se enviase el correo

Comment: No other info other than _Smtpclient send failure_?  What is the host?  Code is quite basic and looks ok, so likely external factors here so may not be able to help too much other than offer alternative tools to email generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the TLS1.2 issue. Most servers nowadays insist on TLS1.2 connections

Upgrading to .NET Framework 4.6 or higher should fix it.

Or you can try adding the following to your startup code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried it and it has worked correctly
Greetings

Comment: Thanks! If it worked, I'd appreciate you marking my answer as the accepted answer :) Happy programming!